# Saving a FixedDocument with images to XPS file

Tags: c#, image, format, xps, fixeddocument

I've saved a **FixedDocument** to **XPS** file for example:

```
void SaveDocument(FixedDocument document, string filePath)
{
    var xps = new XpsDocument(
        filePath, FileAccess.Write, CompressionOption.Maximum);

    var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xps);
    writer.Write(document);

    xps.Close();
}
```

Then I've opened XPS file as ZIP archive and saw my images are kept as PNG files.
How can I change image file format to JPG?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The purpose of using the XpsDocumentWriter is to write an .xps file, which you have done successfully. The filetype of the image data contained within the .xps file should be completely irrelevant.

Comment: I need JPG format for less file size of my documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem: my file size was too big because photographs were being embedded as png instead of jpeg.  I fixed it by converting all png files to jpeg in the package.  I kept the URIs the same to avoid having to update references to the image, but this means the internal URI of your jpegs will end in a misleading ".png".  Obviously this gets more complicated if you want to pick and choose which images you convert to jpeg.

```
public static void ReplacePngsWithJpegs(Package package)
{
    // We're modifying the enumerable as we iterate, so take a snapshot with ToList()
    foreach (var part in package.GetParts().ToList())
    {
        if (part.ContentType == "image/png")
        {
            using (var jpegStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(part.GetStream()))
            {
                image.Save(jpegStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                jpegStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // Cannot access Uri after part is removed, so store it
                var uri = part.Uri; 

                package.DeletePart(uri);

                var jpegPart = package.CreatePart(uri, "image/jpeg");
                jpegStream.CopyTo(jpegPart.GetStream());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've solved this problem by similar way a year ago, but I parsed ZIP archive. Your way is more native and clean. Thanks.